# Chmod permission denied - file permission 600

Tags: html, apache, web, chmod

There's a file on my server that was somehow generated with permission level 600, and I am unable to change the permission or download the file. I get permission denied when I try to change permission, and when I try to download.

Can I force change the permission somehow? I need help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to an SSH shell? sudo chmod? sudo chown?

Answer (score 3):

The permission 600 means the file's owner has permission to read and write to it.  You are not the file's owner if you can't read it.  You need:

```
sudo chown your_username filename
```

Make sure the file should actually be owned by you though.  If you do this you could hinder the ability of the thing that actually generated it to read and write to it.  If the file is not sensitive, you can make it world readable by:

```
chmod a+r filename
```

(If you didn't chown it add sudo.)

This would result in the permission being: 644, allowing anyone to read the file.